# Resharper Unit Test Session hides before running tests

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I am trying to get the R# Unit Test Session window to show when I run unit tests in the solution and stay visible until I change focus or press escape, similar to other VS windows that auto-hide.

What I'm actually seeing is that the window shows until the solution builds then hides before the tests start running.

Is there a setting in VS or R# that I can change to get my desired result?

Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows doesn't have anything relevant. I browsed through all of the options in the ReSharper > Options menus and I couldn't find anything relevant either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like it might be a bug in ReSharper. I've raised an issue that you can track, vote or comment on: [RSRP-451566](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-451566)

Comment: I've added a comment to the issue.